# Android Back Button Utilization Inside ActivityGroup

Tags: android, view, focus, back-button, activitygroup

I am developing an application using TabHost. I am using android default back button to move back to previous activity from current activity by overriding onBackPressed() method inside ActivityGroup of each tab.

Now , the problem is , in one of my activity i have an EditText which get focused when the activity starts. Then , if i press back , it does not go to previous activity , instead it closes the application. By searching about the problem on internet what i have found is that when the EditText get focused which is a child view of activity's view , the activity loss focus and then if back button is pressed , for lack of focus on the current activity it closes the application. Still i am little bit confused or can be say not clear about the problem.

So, any how , i have managed to set and remove focus over EditText on run time using code. But still now , as the EditText does not have focus , if the back button is pressed , it closes the application. I am really confused what's actually going on. So , if anyone have any idea or solution about the problem , please help on the issue. I will appreciate that very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override this behavior by adding Key Listener to your EditText. Try this out,

```
    name_edit.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                    && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Log.i("Back event Trigered", "Back event");
                activitygroup.back();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can u paste your code which has that edit text. See this usually occurs with edittext and webview. see to that u have addressed everything with key listener

Comment: well , in my Activity i have declared some TextView , EditText & Button. created object using findViewById() taking id from xml layout. Also set onclicklistener for the buttons , thats it. Nothing else. But still doing the problem.

Comment: This is what I usually do for my ActivityGroup my fried. It works for me. Sorry if doesn't help you. Please double check your code.

Comment: Ooop!s my bad. Its working actually. I forgot to change some code i have written for focus changing before. For that it was not working. I rechecked my code after u suggested and found that problem. After making them right it's wokring fine. Neways Thanks a lot for your help ... :D I really appreciate tht .... :) Btw , one more thing , does the same problem can occur in WebView ??

Comment: yes. and specially with devices which has track ball. Play safe. U r welcome always

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: Well , i have done something like this. Back button works fine in most activities except those which view's contains EditText. As i said to my question after searching on net , it seems that its a problem of focusing.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 public void onBackPressed() {

      startActivity(new Intent(currentActivity.this, previousActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Well as i am using ActivityGroup for each tab inside TabHost , onBackPressed must be implement in parent class (ActivityGroup) not in child classes(Activity). Beside, startActivity(INTENT) will not start activity within ActivityGroup. So can't use that.